# SQL - "упало" имя таблицы

Tags: sql-server

вчера ещё работал запрос в *SQL Managment Studio*:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2) VALUES ('123', '321')
```

Сегодня он выдаёт ошибку на имя таблицы:

> Сообщение 208, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 1
>
> Недопустимое имя объекта "tablename".`

Перезапускал, не помогло.
Заметил, что такой запрос — срабатывает:

```
INSERT INTO [databasename].[dbo].[tablename] (field1, field2) VALUES ('123', '321')
```

Почему `tablename` превратилось в громоздкое `[databasename].[dbo].[tablename]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас активная база не databasename, а какая-то другая - master, например. Обычно SSMS при открытии sql-файла выставляет активной базу, выбранную в Object Explorer. Выберите databasename в дропдауне на тулбаре. Или выполните

```
USE databasename
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!  
Просто второй день знакомства был с MS SQL и SSMS.